# How to create a Loop in Shell Script to do a specific task?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, loopback

I am trying to clean a Huge database of emails, but when I use the following Grep command, I get "Memory Exhausted" Error.

```
pv "Suppresion-List.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' EMAILS.txt) > RESULT.txt
```

The data set in both file are really huge like more than 5 Million emails, therefore the Linux server gives me "Memory Exhausted" Error.

Therefore I decided to split the file in into small files with 10,000 emails each to process.

```
split -d -l 10000 EMAILS.txt Segment
```

How to create a Bash Script with a loop, where it checks for the created split file in increasing order and starts processing from the first file created - Eg: Segment00

```
pv "Suppresion-List.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' Segment00) > RESULT.txt
```

...then automatically loop the same command and substitute the second segment file in the command - Eg: Segment01

```
pv "Suppresion-List.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' Segment01) > RESULT.txt
```

...carry the loop until the last segment and then finally terminate.

Can you please help me write such Bash script? I cannot figure out how to automatically substitute the segmented files in increasing order automatically in the loop to write a shell script.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `for` loop like this:

```
for i in Segment??
do
pv "Suppresion-List.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' "$i") >> RESULT.txt
done
```

This will exec the command with all `Segment<symbol><symbol>` files and ADD result to `RESULT.txt`

Based on the comment the command should be:

```
pv "RESULT-1.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' "$i") >> RESULT.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. So if the segment file contains 3 numbers (Eg: Segment001, then I should use [???] thrice?

Comment: Right. I use such way to restrict the filenames. You can use also `Segment*` if you are sure only files in question start with this string

Comment: I tested this, there is an issue when I ran this... The final Result file same as the Suppression-List file. What I figured was, in the SECOND ROUND, actually, the Suppresion-List.txt should be replaced by the RESULT-1.txt of the first round output. Only then, we will have the desired result at the end. So how do I do that, Sir? From the Second Round, we need to automatically add the previous round Result file in the place of Suppresion-List.txt and goes on...

Comment: @JoneyWalker, just replace the string after `pv` command. If you do not mean this please clarify editing your question

Comment: Sir, the First round it has to be Suppresion-List.txt itself. Only from the second round, it should get replaced with the output of the first round. Like how you substituted $i automatically, we need to substitute the Output (Result-1.txt) of the First Round to take the place of Suppresion-List.txt. And it should goo on like that...

Comment: Round 1:`pv "Suppresion-List.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' "$i") > RESULT-1.txt`

Comment: Round 2: `pv "RESULT-1.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' "$i") > RESULT-2.txt`

Comment: Round 3: `pv "RESULT-2.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' "$i") > RESULT-3.txt`

Comment: So, we need to create a output file with the incremental number and then that output created file from the previous round should get substituted after `pv` command in place of "Suppresion-List.txt". How do we do that, Sir?

Comment: @JoneyWalker, this change totally the question. I would recommend you to create new question with all those details

Comment: Ok Sir, I will create a New Question and Tag you in that...

Comment: Create a new question Sir [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1403604/how-to-substitute-the-output-file-created-in-round-one-back-into-the-command-in)